# Predicate Error with Oracle VPD/RLS

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help with Oracle's RLS feature. I have never used it before but did some research online about it, however i'm running into a problem.

Here are the steps that I have taken:

1- Create the function:

```
create or replace function
   table_access_policy
   (obj_schema varchar2, obj_name varchar2) return varchar2

is                

v_project varchar2(2000);

begin              

v_project:= '(select project from users where user_name = (select sys_context(''userenv'',''session_user'') from dual))';

return 'project = ' || v_project;       

end;
```

2- Add the security policy

```
Begin

DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY ('db1', 'data', 'access_policy', 'admin', 'table_access_policy', 'SELECT' );

End;
```

3- Run a simple select query on the object

```
select * from db1.data
```

When I do step 3 I get the following error:

ORA-28113: policy predicate has error
28113. 00000 -  "policy predicate has error"
*Cause:    Policy function generates invalid predicate.
*Action:   Review the trace file for detailed error information.
Error at Line: 5 Column: 14

I don't know what could be wrong with the security function. I successfully used it manually on the db1 schema as follows:

```
select * from data
where project = (select project from users where user_name = (select sys_context('userenv','session_user') from dual))
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: what is the need to do "(select project from users where user_name = (select sys_context('userenv','session_user') from dual))" instead of "(select project from users where user_name = sys_context('userenv','session_user'))"

Comment: Alessandro - I tried it the way you suggested and still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your policy function is on the admin schema then you should qualify the select from the users table with its schema:

```
v_project:= '(select project from db1.users where user_name = (select sys_context(''userenv'',''session_user'') from dual))';
```

In addition, you should check the trace file as it recommends as that will show you the exact SQL which is run as well as the real error message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I after I posted my question I had already tried doing what you suggested with specifying db1.users with no success. As for the trace file I'm waiting on our DBA to retrieve it for me since I do not know how to do that

Comment: @AFJ: You may not need the trace file, try looking at `v$vpd_policy`.

Comment: @jonearles - When I try to run SELECT * FROM SYS.V_$VPD_POLICY;
I either get a blank table under the admin schema or a table not found error under the db1 schema

Comment: Ignore my comment about v$vpd_policy, that view doesn't help in this case.  I tried your code, and it works for me when everything is in the same schema.  The issue is permissions.  As @John Doyle points out, you need to specify the schema name.  And you also need to grant the security schema select access on the table.

Comment: @jonearles - Thanks! granting select access to the users table is what did the trick. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a copy of Oracle Enterprise Edition to hand (VPD is Enterprise-edition only), so I can only guess at a few possible causes to the problem:

- Is the table on which you wish to apply the policy `db1.data`?
- Is the function `table_access_policy` under the `admin` schema?
- Have all necessary users have been granted `EXECUTE` privileges on the `table_access_policy` function?

I don't think the issue is case-sensitivity of the arguments, because [Oracle's own examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_rls.htm#i998159) use lower-case object names such as `hr`.

Comment: 1- Yes the table I want to apply the policy on is db1.data
2- Yes, the table_access_policy is under the admin schema
3- Yes, I tried doing this with no success. I am trying to run the query under the db1 schema anyways for testing purposes so I didn't think this would matter