# Oracle RLS/VPD with for loop in policy function

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a followup to an older question about Oracle's row level security feature originally discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957425/predicate-error-with-oracle-vpd-rls)

I needed to modify the because the original code would return more than one results if the user was attached to multiple projects. So now I need to have multiple where conditions (ie where project = project_1 or project = project_2) passed to the security policy for this to work. To do this I tried modifying the code by using a for loop and it is not working...

```
--create function
create or replace function
   table_access_policy
   (obj_schema varchar2, obj_name varchar2) return varchar2

is                

v_project_temp varchar2(9000);

begin              

v_project_temp:= 'declare v_project varchar2(9000);

begin
v_project:= ''project = '';

for c in (select admin.access_list.project from admin.access_list where upper(admin.access_list.user_id) = SYS_CONTEXT (''USERENV'', ''SESSION_USER'')) 

loop

v_project := v_project || c.project_sn || '' or project = '' ;

end loop;

v_project := rtrim(v_project, '' or project = '');

end;';

return v_project_temp;

end;
```

The function saves/runs without any errors, but the policy itself throws an error when it's called. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting the PL/SQL in a string you should run it and build up the v_project string to return. Such as:

```
--create function
create or replace function
   table_access_policy
   (obj_schema varchar2, obj_name varchar2) return varchar2    
is
  v_project varchar2(9000);
begin              
  v_project:= 'project = ';
  for c in (select admin.access_list.project from admin.access_list where upper(admin.access_list.user_id) = SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')) 
  loop
    v_project := v_project ||''''|| c.project_sn ||''''|||| ' or project = ' ;
  end loop;    
  v_project := rtrim(v_project, ' or project = ');    
  return v_project;    
end;
```

Ultimately the value that appears in `v_project` will go straight after a `where` in an SQL statement such as:

```
select * from data;
```

will become

```
select * from date where <v_project>;
```

So only something that follows a `where` should go in v_`project`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wasn't aware I could just pass that to the security policy. I assumed we had to pass queries and the policy had to execute the queries in real time.
Unfortunately I still get "policy predicate has error".
I tried running your code manually without the "Create function..." and it returned the expected results. Any ideas?

Comment: I had left extra quotes around `USERENV` and `SESSION_USER`. I've edited the answer to remove them. See if that works.

Comment: I caught the extra quotes in your response and removed them earlier. Still no luck